# Rserve fails to set up connection in actionPerformed method in Java GUI code

Tags: java, r, user-interface, exception, rserve

I am working on developing a GUI using Java. The GUI at some point would make a connection to R using Rserve to perform some function. I first tested the connection with R using Rserve in the main method the GUI and it worked perfectly. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RserveException,
            REXPMismatchException {

        // Setting up connection to R
        RConnection rc = new RConnection();
        REXP x = rc.eval("R.version.string"); //example to check if connection to R is set
        System.out.println(x.asString());

        // Run the GUI construction in the Event-Dispatching thread for thread-safety
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new GUIMain(); // Let the constructor do the job
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, I want to setup the connection to R in the actionPerformed method (on performing a specific event). Which I am unable to do.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Handle open raw imaging file button and menu item action.
        if ((e.getSource() == OpenImagingFileButton) || (e.getSource() == LoadRawSpectraMenuItem)) {
            int returnVal = fc1.showOpenDialog(GUIMain.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                file = fc1.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());


                REXP x = null; //example to check if connection to R is set
                try {
                    x = rc.eval("R.version.string");
                } catch (RserveException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    System.out.println(x.asString());
                } catch (REXPMismatchException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(" - Done ");
            }
        }
}
```

If I insert **throws RserveException, REXPMismatchException** in this method then I get the error that the overridden method do not throw these exceptions. On surrounding the code withtry-catch block (as shown in the code above), I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUIMain.actionPerformed(GUIMain.java:482)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by adding a new Rconnection in the actionPerformed method.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

        //Handle open raw imaging file button and menu item action.
        if ((e.getSource() == OpenImagingFileButton) || (e.getSource() == LoadRawSpectraMenuItem)) {
            int returnVal = fc1.showOpenDialog(GUIMain.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                file = fc1.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());


                REXP x = null; //example to check if connection to R is set
                try {
                    rc = new RConnection();
                    x = rc.eval("R.version.string");            
                } catch (RserveException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    System.out.println(x.asString());
                } catch (REXPMismatchException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(" - Done ");
            }
        }
}
```